# Granting access only to standby database

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

One of the physical standby databases in my environment is open in read-only mode and used for reporting purposes .
I want to give users access only to this particular standby, not to primary db.

The best approach I found so far is to create `AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE` trigger which checks `v$instance` (or maybe `v$database`), and throws error for depends on  values of `host_name`/`instance_role` columns  .

I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Does your standby happen to be active-datagaurd? That shapes the ability to change passwords for certain users arbitrarily to keep them out of production for reporting purposes.

Comment: @JoshBonello : nope, no data guard.  Standard Edition.

Comment: I'd be on board with @Leigh Riffel's answer, mostly the 3rd bullet. I'd also mention that you'd need to re-copy the pwfile from primary every time you close back down for log application.

Comment: check the DB internal name & user name in after logon trigger; if connected to SB raise error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You could do an OS firewall on the production side, but that wouldn't work if they need production for more limited purposes.
- An after logon database trigger would work, but unfortunately it would also have to run on the primary to disconnect the sessions there.
- You could make it part of your procedures to alter the password on the primary of the user they will use to connect the standby immediately after the standby is opened read-only but before the users are notified of the new password.  In that way they will be able to connect to the standby, but will not be able to connect to the primary.  The password just set for the primary would then be the password you delivered to them after the next open of the standby.
- You could enable the user just before the standby is opened and then disable the user immediately after before the users are notified that the standby is open.  This would allow the password to stay the same, but does introduce a window of vulnerability that you may be able to mitigate if you have an outage window on the primary and can bring down the listener or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a TNS entry that only points to the Read-Only standby for the reporting tools/users to connect to. It's simpler to administer than a trigger, especially if this standby ever needs to become primary for any purpose. The logon database trigger would be another step in the process before services could functionally use the database.

Per net-new requirements in comments: This solution is not valid.

Comment: This would only work if they don't have the TNS entry for production and even then would only be security through obscurity, which seldom is sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have full control over all users' computers, and I can't guarantee that they don't use , for instance, easy connect method.

Comment: This solution assumes that the reporting users can make a trivial change to their connect strings to accommodate. 

There is no real mention of security requirements. It is assumed that the userload is using a TNS entry to connect to this database regardless, he can simply make the entry unable to connect to the primary. I'm not sure what you mean that this is only by obscurity, for this particular solution.

Comment: @JoshBonello The op is asking for the users to have access only to the standby and not the primary.  The fact that they are even considering a trigger indicates that they want to prevent them from connecting to the primary, not just in a procedural sense, but in a technical sense.

Comment: @JoshBonello Security through obscurity means that if they were able to discover the connection information for production (probably not to difficult) they could use the same username and password to connect to production which the op is trying to prevent.  So, the only security is the obscurity of the connection information, which isn't real security.